# Did Food Prices Spur the Arab Spring?

Tags: history, africa

Dalia Mortada writes for PBS in [Did Food Prices Spur the Arab Spring?](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/updates/world-july-dec11-food_09-07/):

> One of the driving forces behind the Arab Spring, some contend, is the high cost of food. A combination of shrinking farmlands, weather and poor water allocation is helping contribute to higher prices and, in turn, anti-government sentiment, according to analysts.

Peter Thiel said in an [interview](http://fortune.com/2012/07/17/transcript-schmidt-and-thiel-smackdown/):

> I think the Arab Spring, I think the fundamental driver for that was the food prices went up 50 percent and people were going to starve and I think it’s smug and complacent to pretend that it was anything other than that.

Was the Arab Spring caused by rising food prices?

Comment: How would we turn this from opinion into empirically based?

Comment: @Oddthinking The question is basically about causation. I don't think we have closed questions about claims of causation in the past. If you have ideas about how to make the question more empirically based feel free to go ahead.

Comment: I agree it is about causation, but it is someone's opinion about causation. I can't see how to turn that into something with empirical evidence; there's no way to run a randomised control trial. The accepted answer demonstrates correlation with a reference, and then shrugs and says "maybe/maybe not" for causation.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think the accepted answer does provide better evidence than being found in the quoted source in the question.
It's not a perfect situation but I think the improved amount of empirical evidence is valuable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On one hand, slogans of the Arab Spring included chants about access to bread, and there is a strong correlation between the FAO Food Price Index and two waves of protests. The dotted blue line here shows the date of a warning from the authors of the cited paper that protests would occur: ([source](http://necsi.edu/research/social/food_crises.pdf))

[image: Correlation in 2008 and 2011]

On the other hand, one source denies any correlation between the Tunisian food price index and the start of protests, and points out that a public announcement that food prices would be lowered did not stop the protests. ([source](https://www.newsecuritybeat.org/2014/04/high-food-prices-arab-spring/)) Furthermore, in other countries like Morocco, Jordan, and Algeria, people spend 40% of their budget on food, compared to 6% in America, but despite protests and riots those governments were not overthrown. ([source](http://www.afdb.org/en/news-and-events/article/the-political-economy-of-food-security-in-north-africa-10020/))

From this we can gather that the Arab Spring was different from the 2007-8 food riots in its political motivations and desire for regime change, as well as the weakness of the governments being protested against. Food prices may have been a "spur" but people's motivations were more multifaceted than that, as evidenced by the state of the Arab world today.